# Finding the shortest path with online services in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, shortest-path

I am looking for a plugin that can detriment the shortest path between two points in QGIS. 
It should not be a street line between the points, but the shortest way with consideration to the roads of the area in interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice plugin that made for this purpose by [CBS UYGULAMA](https://cbsuygulama.wordpress.com/online-routing-mapper-en/) and called 
"Online Routing Mapper". The project is an open source distributed with [GPL v3 license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License).
In order of this plugin you need to download and install it. As you can expected it's called Online Routing Mapper [image]
Once you click on the plugin icon this window will open and you need to point on the start and locations and also choose the online service provider [image]
Once you it's done you will have the shortest path as a temporary layer without any information in the attribute table [image]
If you want to work with this layer you need to save it as a new layer and once you did it you can work with it, for example finding the length of the layer in KM  [image]